# Swagger UI gives 404 when app is running in Docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, nginx, swagger

In my project I have set up Swagger with Swashbuckle like so in my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Example API", Version = "v1" });
            });

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
```

When I run my application from Visual Studio I can access `localhost:123456/swagger` and get the API documentation, like it should be. However when I run my application through Docker with `docker-compose up` and access `example_IP/swagger` I get a 404 not found. Testing the `example_IP` with Postman gives me the expected data, so nothing wrong with the IP or the backend. I have tried with several different URLs, `/swagger`, `/swagger-ui.html` etc, but no difference. Are there any specific configurations that must be written in the Dockerfile or elsewhere to be able to access the Swagger documentation when running in a Docker container? I am running my backend through an nginx reverse proxy, not sure if that matters or not.

Docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  dotnet-backend:
    container_name: dotnet-backend
    build: .
   #expose:
    #  - "80"
    links:
      - mssql-db
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
  nginx-reverse-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-reverse-proxy
    build: ./nginx/
    #command: tail -F /dev/null
    command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    #  - "443:443"
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    links:
      - dotnet-backend
  mssql-db:
    container_name: mssql-db
    #image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    build: ./Database
    environment: 
      - SA_PASSWORD=password
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    volumes:
     - ./Database/:/scripts/
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    expose:
      - "1433"
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c 
      - |
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o out Project.csproj

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectApi.dll", "--environment=Development"]
```

Comment: accordingly to your compose file you are exposing backend API container on port 8000 to host network (80 inside docker network). How do you try to open swagger UI in your browser? If you are doning it on host machine (not inside compose network) - it should be http://localhost:8000/swagger

Comment: When running on my host machine (that is from visual studio) I access swagger on http://localhost:57467/swagger as that is set in the launchSettings.json.

Comment: I don't see where you map 57467 port of your container

Comment: Try accessing dotnet-backend/swagger from inside the compose network. Is the application really listnening on this port?

Comment: Hey @PalBo,
What was the problem? I have same issue.
I do curl from same container - everything is working, except swagger. Swagger endpoint call response is 404...

>/ # curl -iv localhost/swagger/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /swagger/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2020 16:06:10 GMT
< Server: Kestrel

Comment: Yep, bump. Anyone got a fix for this?

Comment: Verify swagger isn't only being loaded in a specific environment...such as in a ```IsDevelopment()``` block - this is especially important with the newer net 5.0 templates.

Answer (score 28):

I doubt this will help the original question, but I just hit this.
Now that the WebApi templates have Swagger built-in, it can be tricky when running a container via manual steps (docker run) or Visual Studio.

The Swagger UI is now in a "Development" block by default:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "test v1"));
}
```

This works fine in Visual Studio's Docker tools, but if you build the Dockerfile without making changes, it's built as Release, and Swagger won't be accessible.

So, this is just one gotcha when moving a container into production if you want Swagger still available.

The fix is to move the two swagger lines out of the `env.IsDevelopment()` conditional.

Comment: You saved my remaining hairs on my head ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by using the containers hostnames in the reverse proxy instead of using the containers ip addresses. Swagger UI now works fine.