# .NET Core API docker can not access

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, networking, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to dockerize my .net core rest api app.
I refer to [MS Menual](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-5.0) which give docker sample and commands guidance and It worked well.

So, to try [dockerizing] myself, I created .Net Core Rest API app and checked 'Use Docker Support'.

I built image with 'Dockerfile' had been given by MS.
Below is Dockerfile

```
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["dockersupport.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./dockersupport.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "dockersupport.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "dockersupport.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dockersupport.dll"]
```

And I build it with
`>$ docker build -t docksupport .`

And run with
`>$ docker run --rm -it -p 5000:80 --name dockersupport dockersupport`

And server was running well. However I can't access to API swagger page.

When I tried to build/run with visual studio only, It showed swagger page well.

I tried to access to web page with url : 'localhost:5000/swagger/index.html' docker and local both.

I can't understand why MS sample app works well but my app doesn't. I wonder what is the differece between their and mine.

Would you share your knowledge or how can I access web page of my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my code, swagger UI would be shown if environment is **Development**. However, I just set my docker environment **Production**.

I refer to this post [Swagger UI gives 404 when app is running in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824036/swagger-ui-gives-404-when-app-is-running-in-docker-container)
and I deleted **if** condition, It works well